# Display output from a XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

If suppose I have the following XML file in the following format:

```
<Employee>
  <EmpInfo>
     <Name> 1 </Name>
     <Age> 23 </Age>
     <Salary> 23234 </Salary>
  </EmpInfo>
  <EmpInfo>
     <Name> 2 </Name>
     <Age> 234 </Age>
     <Salary> 54 </Salary>
  </EmpInfo> *and so on in the similar fashion*
</Employee>
```

I want to display the output.

**EDIT:**

I tried the basic way like this:

```
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\new.xml");
root = doc.DocumentElement;
txtName1.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("name1")[0].InnerText;
textBox2.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("empid1")[0].InnerText;
textBox3.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("deptt1")[0].InnerText;
textBox4.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("name2")[1].InnerText;
textBox5.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("empid2")[1].InnerText;
textBox6.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("deptt2")[1].InnerText;
```

Is there any other way apart from using GetElementsByTagName?

Comment: I wonder why people dont use `LINQ2XML`..its so simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code will give you rows in the tabular form:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"[xml file]");

var rows = doc.Descendants("EmpInfo").Select(e => new()
{
    Name = e.Element("Name").Value,
    Age = e.Element("Age").Value,
    Salary = e.Element("Salary").Value
});
```

OR

```
class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

var rows = doc.Descendants("EmpInfo").Select(e => new Entity()
{
    Name = e.Element("Name").Value,
    Age = Convert.ToInt32(e.Element("Age").Value),
    Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Element("Salary").Value)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read data in `DataSet`and assign that `DataSet` to GridView ..

check below code

```
   string myXMLfile = Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml");
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
// Create new FileStream with which to read the schema.
      System.IO.FileStream fsReadXml = new System.IO.FileStream(myXMLfile, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

      try
      {
          ds.ReadXml(fsReadXml);
          gridView1.DataSource = ds;
          gridView1.DataBind();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           Response.Write(ex.Message);
      }
      finally
      {
          fsReadXml.Close();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the XML data to an array, then iterate through each of the EmpInfos, printing the employee name, age, and salary with a printf-like function. Perhaps print the headings as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml("xml file path");
```

Then you can use the dataset along with datatable and subsequent operations.e.g with repeater or datagrid or likewise

Answer (score 0):

Your question may have a broad answer so better first you try the following
Try to Read the Xml usinng [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx)

Try to Create a table using [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable)